# Passing variable from PHP to AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

Here I'm passing session value to AS3 but I don't want to send any other thing or content of the page like HTML code and on the other side I don't want to user see the *session:x* on the page.

```
<?php
session_start();
 $session = $_SESSION['myusername'] ;
 if(!isset( $_SESSION['myusername'])){
    header('location:../login.html');
} else{
 echo "session:".$session;
 header('location:speaking.html');
}
?>
<html>
<!-- some HTML code-->
</html>
```

**Update:**

```
 var sesname:String;
 var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/speaking.php");
 loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
 loader.load(req);
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, connectComplete);
 function connectComplete(event:Event):void{
    var session:String = event.target.data;

    sesname= session;
    trace(sesname);
    nextFrame();
}
```

Comment: you mean *retrieving* data from php, not *passing* from php?

Comment: @ihsan.When a user logged in, I need his username to send to AS3. Only his username not all content in the page after or before echo. I don't know is there correct my AS3 or not.

Comment: is this command `var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/speaking.php");` calls the above php code? To retrieve data from url request, you must return only a variable-value pair strings, eg. `<?php echo "var1=val1&var2=val2" ?>`

Comment: Yes. I used your suggestion FlashVars parameter of the swf flash object to prevent the user see the echo on the page but in Flash output it shows all content of the page not only session variable content.

Comment: I improve my answer with more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Depends how your AS3 code looks, you can add parameter to your query to distinct it from user and use it to detect it in PHP:

```
urlVars = new URLVariables();
urlReq.data = urlVars;
urlVars.as3 = 1;
```

And in your code:

```
} elseif($_GET['as3']) {
  echo "session:".$session;
  header('location:speaking.html');
}
```

After `echo()` you can use `exit()` to stop executing php/html code.

Comment: Therefore I will lose my html! But I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between PHP and AS3 is something like the following.

First, initiate a session in php and output the swf flash object in html. In your case, I don't think it is necessary to pass session variable to the object.

```
<?php
session_start();
// some other codes
?>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="myFlashMovie" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="myFlashMovie.swf" />
</object>
```

Second, inside the swf flash object, the AS3 load a php script that will return only name-value pair if it was called from AS3 (notice the `fromFlash` query string).

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/speaking.php?fromFlash=1");
```

Third, in `speaking.php`, output only string with containing the necessary name-value pairs. You might need to `urlencode` the value.

```
<?php
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['myusername'];
if(!isset( $_SESSION['myusername'])) {
    header('location:../login.html');
} else {
    if (isset($_GET['fromFlash']) && $_GET['fromFlash'] == 1) {
        echo "sessionVar=" . $_SESSION['myusername'];
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "session:".$session;
        header('location:speaking.html');
    }
}
?>
<html>
<!-- some HTML code-->
</html>
```

Finally, the AS3 extract data from the called speaking.php. Notice the `sessionVar` variable is the same as the output above `echo "sessionVar=" . $_SESSION['myusername'];`

```
// this is the same swf object in step 2
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/speaking.php?fromFlash=1");
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, connectComplete);
function connectComplete(event:Event):void{
   var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

   trace(variables.sessionVar);
   nextFrame();
}
```